# Can't access checkbox values from backing bean in ADF/JDeveloper

Tags: oracle-adf

New to both ADF and JDeveloper. Also first time posting on Stack Exchange.

The business case:

I want to get some data from a database, display as a tree with checkboxes at only the leaves (the lowest level nodes). 
I then want the user to be able to check arbitrary checkboxes, click a submit button and then have the application do various operations on the data (specifically, which checkboxes are checked) in a managed bean. The data does not need to be saved back to the database, only operated on programmatically.

The steps I've taken:

I've set up my Entity Objects that tie into the database, created the View Objects and added them to the Application Module. I then added a Boolean transient attribute called Selected to the lowest level view object, setting Updatable to Always. I created the Facelets page and dragged and dropped to create a tree that shows up just like I want it.

I created another binding to the Selected attribute from my Data Control, and created a selectBooleanCheckbox right after the outputText under the nodeStamp facet. I then tweaked the rendered attribute so it would only render for the lowest level nodes.

So far so good. Tree displays and looks great.

I then created a commandButton and created an action binding to a method called submitTree in a request-scoped managed bean called TreeTest. The form component of my Facelet page now looks like this:

`<af:form id="f1">
    <af:commandButton text="Submit" id="cb2" action="#{TreeTestBean.submitTree}" />
    <af:tree summary="A generic summary." id="t1"
             value="#{bindings.TopLevelVO.treeModel}" var="node" rowSelection="none"
             selectionListener="#{bindings.TopLevelVO.treeModel.makeCurrent}">
        <f:facet name="nodeStamp">
            <af:group id="g1">
                <af:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{node.Selected}" id="sbc1"
                                       rendered="#{node.AccessDisplayName != null ? true : false}" />
                <af:outputText value="#{node}" id="ot1"/>
            </af:group>
         </f:facet>
    </af:tree>
</af:form>`

I am now using the iterator approach on the bindings and have edited my backing bean code to look like the following:

public class TreeTestBean{

```
public void submitTree(){
    BindingContainer bindings = ADFUtils.getBindingContainer();
    DCIteratorBinding dcIteratorBinding = (DCIteratorBinding) bindings.get("TopLevelVOIterator");
    TopLevelVOImpl topLevelVO = (TopLevelVOImpl) dcIteratorBinding.getViewObject();
    RowSetIterator rowSetIterator = topLevelVO.createRowSetIterator(null);

    while (rowSetIterator.hasNext()){
        TopLevelVORowImpl applicationVORow = (TopLevelVORowImpl) rowSetIterator.next();
        ViewRowSetImpl secondLevelRowSet = (ViewRowSetImpl) topLevelVORow.getsecondLevelVO();
        while (secondLevelRowSet.hasNext()){
            SecondLevelVORowImpl secondLevelVORow = (SecondLevelVORowImpl) secondLevelRowSet.next();
            ViewRowSetImpl bottomLevelRowSetImpl = (ViewRowSetImpl) secondLevelpVORow.getBottomLevelVO();
            while (bottomLevelRowSetImpl.hasNext()){
                BottomLevelVORowImpl bottomLevelVORow = (BottomLevelVORowImpl) bottomLevelRowSetImpl.next();
                logger.info(bottomLevelVORow.getBottomLevelName() + " selected: " + bottomLevelVORow.getSelected());
        }
    }
}
rowSetIterator.closeRowSetIterator();
}
```

So, it appears that I am iterating through the tree correctly. getBottomLevelName correctly prints out the value I want. The checkboxes start as null. When I check a few of them, the ones that I check will show up as false (and the checks get cleared). All the rest stay null. I feel like there is something in the scope and/or lifecycle that I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Updated code to reflect changes made due to Shay's answer.

Comment: There apparently is no real answer to this. I chucked the Tree idea and went with nested tables. Everything works fine now.